# Existence of right inverse surjective continuous linear operator on Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $X,Y$ be a Banach space and let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective continuous linear operator. As mentinoed in this [stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786072/left-and-right-inverses-of-linear-operators), we know there exists a right inverse linear operator.

But I want to know whether $T$ has a continuous right linear inverse $S$, i.e., there exists a **bounded** linear operator $S:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $T\circ S=\mathrm{id}_Y$.

In the case of finite dimensional vector spaces, linear operator is bounded linear operator. So there is nothing to prove.

This question is arisen when I study sum space of two Banach spaces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301255/surjective-bounded-operator-in-banach-spaces-without-bounded-right-inverse